# Flask shell isn't finding submodule of directory, raises AttributeError

Tags: python, flask, cookiecutter

Using [cookiecutter-flask](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask), I created a new blueprint/submodule called `site` that is modeled after the `user` submodule across all the relevant files, tests, etc. Tests are passing, DB created, and `flask run` works, but when I try to enter `flask shell` I get

> AttributeError: module 'webapp.site' has no attribute 'models'

Here's the project structure and relevant bits from code:

--- Project Structure ---

```
├── assets
├── autoapp.py
├── webapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── site
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── user
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── webpack
├── tests

--- webapp/__init__.py
"""Main application package."""

--- webapp/user/__init__.py ---
from . import views

--- webapp/site/__init__.py ---
from . import views

--- webapp/app.py ---
from webapp import site, user
...
def register_shellcontext(app):
    """Register shell context objects."""
    def shell_context():
        """Shell context objects."""
        print(dir(site))
        return {
            'db': db,
            'User': user.models.User,
-->         'Site': site.models.Site,
        }
```

--- ERROR OUTPUT ---
AttributeError: module 'webapp.site' has no attribute 'models'

I get the error output when I try to enter `flask shell`. The `user` module works fine, but `site` barfs. If I open Python REPL, I can `from webapp import site` and then do `site.models` just fine. I can also change the import in `app.py` to `from webapp.site.models import Site` and that works - but I still would like to know why the other way isn’t working. I’ve also tried blanking out the `site/__init__.py` (doesn't work) and importing `models` to `site/__init__.py` (which does work).

If I add a `print(dir(site))` immediately after importing it in `app.py`, I see

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'views']
```

I'm at a loss of what is going on here and why `user` is working but not `site`.

Comment: Could you tell why in the app.py file you are importing site and user from axon package? I can't see axon package in your project structure you provided.

Comment: @Alex - corrected that line, it should've been webapp

Comment: Is your __init__.py file in the webapp directory empty? If not could you also provide its content?

Comment: It is empty except for the docstring, added to OP. I also added a link to cookiecutter-flask to show what the code looks like otherwise.